# "Missing ) After Argument List" Error -- Can't Find A Bug

Tags: javascript, debugging

I am very new to JavaScript, so I apologize if I made a dumb mistake, but I cannot find the an error here. I am creating a 'choose your own adventure'-type game, and it's gone smoothly until I added in some do/while loops and if/else statements.

I've been testing for a while, and by process of elimination I have found the error only appears when I have this line:

```
if (worst === (options[0] || options[1])) {
    options.splice(2, 0, best);
```

but for the life of me I can't find the mistake.

If it helps, this is the entire script:

```
var options = ["STRENGTH", "SPEED", "SMARTS"];
alert("Before we begin our journey, let's learn a little bit  about you.");
var user = prompt("What is your name?").toUpperCase();
do {
var bestLoop = false;
var best = prompt("So " + user + ", what is your greatest ability, STRENGTH, SPEED, or SMARTS?").toUpperCase();
if (best === ("STRENGTH" || "SPEED" || "SMARTS")) {
        var offset = options.indexOf(best);
        if (offset != -1) {
            options.splice(offset, 1);
        }   
    } else {
    alert("Please choose either STRENGTH, SPEED, or SMARTS as your greatest ability.");
        bestLoop = true;
    }
} while (bestLoop);
alert("Great! So " + best + " is yor greatest ability.");
do {
var worstLoop = false;
var worst = prompt("So which is your greatest weakness, " + options[0] + " or " + options[1] + "?").toUpperCase();
if (worst === (options[0] || options[1])) {
    options.splice(2, 0, best);
} else {
    alert("Please choose either " + options[0] + " or " + options[1] " as your greatest weakness.");
    worstLoop = true;
}
} while (worstLoop);
alert("Great. So your name is " + user + ", " + best + " is your greatest ability, and " + worst + " is your greatest weakness.");
```

Again, I apologize if there is something I overlooked, but this has been driving me crazy for a few hours and I can't seem to find the issue.

Comment: I don't think this is doing what you think it's doing `best === ("STRENGTH" || "SPEED" || "SMARTS")`, nor this line `worst === (options[0] || options[1])`

Comment: I've tested it, and the system works just fine now. It checks if the response is one of the above, and if not loops to the question again. Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: How did you test it? That doesn't do what you want because it makes no sense. Non-empty strings evaluate to true. Only the first one will be evaluated against the condition. Check this, no alert: http://jsbin.com/ihiqeg/1/edit

Comment: Huh, I only tested it with choosing strength. Is there a way to do that correctly?

Comment: Ah, it's as simple as adding best === to each statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a "+" in line

`alert("Please choose either " + options[0] + " or " + options[1]" as your greatest weakness.");`

So it should be:

`alert("Please choose either " + options[0] + " or " + options[1] + " as your greatest weakness.");`

This what was confusing the interpreter.

*Suggestion: if you can find a way to configure your text editor, have it work with jslint or jshint. This saves tons of time by finding that missing operator or parenthese for you.*